# Sequencer is Rendering In Eevee Vs Cycles and looks different than Viewport

Tags: cycles-render-engine, objects, 3d-view, layers, compositing-nodes

I camera tracked some footage in my alley to try and composite some models but when I hit render either all my models disappear when rendering from viewport or I get a weird shading when rendering from the Sequencer.
Attached is an image of what I'm seeing.
[image]

Comment: In Scene Properties -> Post Processing do you have Sequencer checked?  If so, does unchecking it help?

Comment: Unchecking it doesn't help. The viewport still renders without my objects.